# How can I create a SelectList with multiple selected values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to set multiple values in a select list:

```
SelectList List = new SelectList(MyListItems, "valField", "dataField", <selected values>);
```

What object/values do I use for  to select multiple items?

Answer (score 31):

You want to use [MultiSelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470159.aspx) instead which has a constructor to meet your needs:

```
public MultiSelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    IEnumerable selectedValues
)
```

Comment: okay...will that work with  @Html.DropDownList() in my razor code?

Comment: no, you'll have to use Html.ListBox... native HTML dropdown lists don't support multi-select.  See http://blog.garypretty.co.uk/index.php/2010/02/26/multi-select-list-box-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @RobertLevy you can use the DropDownList like this:
@Html.DropDownList("yourName", yourMultiSelectList, new { multiple = "" })

Comment: @Matus I know I'm "coming from the future" now, but it's better to stick to Html.ListBox / Html.ListBoxFor since Razor, for some reason, doesn't "remember" the previously selected options properly when using DropDownList or DropDownListFor with a MultiSelectList.

Comment: Perfect was looking for the MultiSelect Option for 2 days now

Answer (score 19):

Example:

```
class Person
{
    int Id{ get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

...

var people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person{ Id = 1, Name = "Steve" },
    new Person{ Id = 2, Name = "Bill" },
    new Person{ Id = 3, Name = "John" },
    new Person{ Id = 4, Name = "Larry" }
}
SelectList List = new MultiSelectList(people, "Id", "Name", new[]{ 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the The Harvest Chosen jQuery plugin. See my tutorial [Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) which shows how to do this.