# SelectList with multiple selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, multi-select, selectlist

How can i create a SelectList with multiple selected items?. I want to bind the SelectList to Razor dropdown and if its a single selected item i am using this code

```
        List<SchoolApp.Models.Accounts.role> roles = accRepo.GetRoles();
        if (selected > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.RolesList = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "RoleName");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.RolesList = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "RoleName", selected);
        }
```

And in Razor i used the syntax

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">         
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, (SelectList)ViewBag.RolesList, "Select", new { @class = "multiselect", @multiple = "multiple", @style = "width: 450px;height:300px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId)
    </div>
```

But how can i set mutiple items as selected on this SelectList?I tried

```
  ViewBag.RolesList = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "RoleName",, new[] { 2, 3, 10, 11 });
```

But multiple items are not seems to be set as selected. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't select multiple items with a `SelectList`

You need to use [MultiSelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470159.aspx) and use it like this :

```
public MultiSelectList(
  IEnumerable items,
  string dataValueField,
  string dataTextField,
  IEnumerable selectedValues
)
```

You can also look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839760/how-can-i-create-a-selectlist-with-multiple-selected-values)

Comment: I change the code to 
  ViewBag.ActionsList = new    MultiSelectList(actions, "Id", "Name", new[] { 2, 3, 10, 11 });
but its returning the exception

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.
So is any other way to use this with Dropdownlist

Comment: Is `actions` a IEnumerable ? Do fields `Id` and `Name` exist ?

Comment: Solved that error . but still selection is not working
in code
 ViewBag.ActionsList = new    MultiSelectList(actions, "Id", "Name", new[] { 2, 3, 10, 11 });
and in razor 
 Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActionId, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.ActionsList, new { class = "multiselect", multiple = "", style = "width: 450px;height:300px" })
But no items are selected . Whats wrong in my case?